# Run Ionic, Cordova, Angular app on Windows 10 tablet using USB

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic3, windows-10-mobile

I want to run my Ionic, Cordova, Angular app directly on Win 10 tablet using CLI commands.

In this app, there is Windows and Web platforms added.

I used `ionic cordova run windows --device`, but does not work even I enabled Developer mode on tablet.

When I used this command the windows local device run.

Any help to run on tablet windows 10?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tabet windows 10 is one of the independent devices. This means cannot enable USB debugger even you enabled Developer mode.

However, if you want to test your app you have only one fast way.

1. build your windows platform project.
2. Open Visual studio and sign your app to windows app store project.
3. uploaded to your Microsoft developer account with you app submission.

This is only the case to run you app on Tablet windows 10

Answer (score 2):

if you can connect your tablet to your destop, you can try `ionic cordova run windows --list` to check if your device is detected by cordova.

If your tablet is detected, you can try`ionic cordova run windows --appx=uap -target=<targetName>` to deploy your app to the tablet. `<targetName>` is retrieved by command `ionic cordova run windows --list`.

If your tablet is not detected, try to package your app and copy it to your tablet then run it to install. For details about package your app, please refer to [Manual app packaging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/manual-packaging-root).

Comment: thank you very much for this answer, but I used Ionic 3 and I do not know why my tablet does not listed. should I enable USB debug and how can be on tablet?

Comment: Also, I don't know how to enable USB debugging.

Comment: Ionic/cordova eventually generates a UWP project, when you add windows platform. You can use Manual app packaging procedure with the generated UWP project.

Comment: Some windows device like surface, doesn't not support USB debugging or installation. Because it functions as a standalone PC. You can only copy the generated Appx package to the tablet and install it manually or build directly in that tablet.

Comment: thank you for the answer, but what about Electron packager. I have tried but got fail with "A java script error occurred in the main presses". What do you think?

Comment: Electron packager is only for [Electron based apps](https://electron.atom.io/). I don't think you can use it for ionic apps.